# ASP.NET page maintain State after postback with EnableViewState = false

Tags: asp.net

In ASP.NET webpage, I have set the EnableViewState to false to the page and all the controls of the page. Still I am getting the PostBack data in the Controls.

Is there any way to remove this? 
How do we remove the page life cycle event like restore PostBackData? 
Actually _ViewState is maintained for all controls. I am not clarified from MSDN as well.

Comment: Currently I am using VS2010 and .Net framework 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Postback data has nothing to do with ViewState.

If you don't want Postback data, why are you using Post?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My doubt is that I have disabled the viewstate from Page and all the child controls, still I am getting data are auto-populated to the controls like dropdown, textbox, etc in each page postback or control event like Button click (server control). How it is possible? I don't want this behaviour. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Because you re-bind your datas after each PostBack

You can use `!IsPostBack` in your Bind

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
  //Bind your datas just for load, and disable your ViewState, that will erase your selected datas
}
```